# numpy maximum element axis = 1 gives Deprecation warning

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using Python 3.7 and numpy 1.18.1 and I have a 3 x 2 numpy array as follows:

```
y = np.array([
    [10, 2],
    [13, 15],
    [19, 1]
    ])
```

Now, to find maximum values across columns-

```
np.amax(y, axis = 0)
# array([19, 15])

# Find indices of maximum elements across columns-
np.where(y == np.amax(y, axis = 0))
```

And to find maximum values across rows-

```
np.amax(y, axis = 1)
# array([10, 15, 19])
```

But, when I try to find indices of maximum values across columns-

```
np.where(y == np.amax(y, axis = 1))
```

It gives me the following warning:

> :1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise
>   comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
>   np.where(y == np.amax(y, axis = 1))

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This is interesting, I imagine it would work for `axis=1` and not for `axis=0` due to broadcasting rule. Apparently I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's about the uneven shapes in here - `np.amax` returns `ndarray` with shape `1,x` now when you take `axis=1` and in your case you have an array of size `3,2` which you try to compare against single column of size `1,3` - it just doesn't fit.

Reshape to make it work:

```py
np.where(y == np.amax(y, axis = 1).reshape(-1,1))
```